# Insert an if statement in go tmpl range

Tags: go-templates

In my project, in the `index.tmpl` file is the range function defined: `{{ range $index, $jb := .Jailbreaks }}` which iterates through the `Jailbreaks` array.

I was wondering if there is a way to check if the $index is on a defined position. So for this I tried `{{ if $index == 0 }}` but on compiling I get the error

> Error rendering `index` template: template: index.tmpl:63: unexpected "=" in operand

Do I have to define a function in the main.go file to complete this task? 
I am [working with this project](https://github.com/cj123/canijailbreak.com) for everyone who is wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `{{ if eq $index 0 }}`. See https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Actions and https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Functions.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, this works pretty good! And also thanks a lot for the links. 
Now I am wondering if I can check if a third item is reached (`$index` is 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, ...), therefor I think I would need an block argument? Or I am completely wrong with my thinking?

Comment: In that case, you may want to look into something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/36369436/5085211